# R graph degree.distribution not working

Tags: r, graph, distribution, igraph

I cannot figure out why `degree.distribution` is not working for me. I have tried on R i386 3.0.0 and R x64 3.0.0. Here is the simple script to generate a graph and show its distribution:

```
library(igraph)

testG = graph.empty(n=10, directed=TRUE)
for(row in 1 : 5) {
    src = row
    dest = row + 1
    testG = add.edges(testG, rbind(src, as.numeric(dest)))
    if(row %% 2 == 0) {
        dest = row + 2
        testG = add.edges(testG, rbind(src, as.numeric(dest)))
    }
}
testG

testD = degree.distribution(testG, v=V(testG), cumulative=FALSE)
testD
plot(1 : length(testD), testD, "h", main="Website Graph Degree Distribution", xlab="Degree", ylab="Probability of Degree")
degree(testG)
```

testG shows: `IGRAPH D--- 10 7 --` (makes sense).
testD shows: `NULL` (why?).
The plot is with just one value at (1,1). But the graph contains nodes with other degrees, as evidenced by the output of degree(testG), which is `[1,3,2,4,2,2,0,0,0,0]`.

Comment: That is a bug: you can report it to the package author. The function uses `hist`, whose result used to have an `intensities` field, but it was removed in R 3.0.0 (one can use `density` instead).

Comment: Thank you! I had a suspicion that might be the case. Running my script on R x64 2.15.2 works perfectly.

Comment: Was already reported and fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/1164523 As a workaround define your own `degree.distribution` function, very simple, you can copy it from igraph, and then change `intensities` to `density`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the degree.distribution function. Details can be find on following link.
[Can't replicate result with degree.distribution function of igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715697/cant-replicate-result-with-degree-distribution-function-of-igraph)