# Can't replicate result with degree.distribution function of igraph

Tags: igraph

I [found](http://www.r-bloggers.com/igraph-degree-distribution-count-elements/) this very simple example online:

```
library(igraph)    
g <- graph.ring(5)
plot(g)
summary(g)
degree.distribution(g)
```

I got the same results up to `degree.distribution(g)`while instead of `[1] 0 0 1` I get `NULL`.

Since I have exactly the same problem with [this](http://horicky.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/basic-graph-analytics-using-igraph.html) example (NULL result to function `degree.distribution` instead of `[1] 0.135 0.280 0.315 0.110 0.095 0.050 0.005 0.010`) I wonder if the problem might be in the package installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `degree.distribution` function in igraph 0.6.5 does not work well with R 3.0.0 and newer because of some changes in the return value of the `hist` function in R. The developers [already know about it](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/257) and it will be fixed in the next release. Until it is released, you have to work around the bug by modifying the source code of the `degree.distribution` function according to [this patch](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/commit/0567c2694a99686bbd1855299822ad52dcd5989a).

Comment: How can I open up the package source code, so to modify it? I had a look at the package folder but I couldn't find any editable text file.

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: R version 3.0.1 Patched (2013-08-27 r63725) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

Comment: If you are running Mac OS X, I think the easiest is to download the most recent 0.6.5 snapshot of the R package from https://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/list and then install it using `R CMD INSTALL` from the command line.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get degree.distribution right with [0.7](https://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/detail?name=igraph_nightly_0.7-38b76dd-20130825.tar.gz&can=2&q=) (but not with [0.6.5](https://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/detail?name=igraph_nightly_0.6.5-bf94cba-20130530.tar.gz&can=2&q=)). Also I had to install _gcc_ and reinstall with _brew_ _gmp_.